# to find the file whether it exists in registry editor through cpp program

Tags: c++, windows

I have tried using `CRegKey regKey;` but this is not working. this is the path which I want to know whether it exists or not. If not I'll install the driver and if it is there then I will uninstall it setting the if condition and changing the bool values.

```
"Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\yash\ta567.1 Drivers_x64"
```

Comment: Please show the actual code you are having trouble with. Also, `"Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\"` is not a valid prefix for a Registry key string

Comment: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ETAS\ES584.1 Drivers_x64"

Comment: still not a valid key string in Registry APIs. You can't specify the hive name in the string itself (current user, local machine, etc), you have to start at the root key in the hive. The hive is passed in separately

Comment: see the code which REMY has done below... refer to it... it is right thing but i am getting error while using CRegKey. Could u please help in solving that.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```cpp
#include <atlbase.h>

CRegKey regKey;
LONG lRet = regKey.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("SOFTWARE\\ETAS\\ES584.1 Drivers_x64"), KEY_QUERY_VALUE);
if (lRet == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    // key exists...
    regKey.Close();
}
else if (lRet == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
{
    // does not exist...
}
else
{
    // error opening key...
}
```

Comment: identifier CRegKey is undefined... what should i do with this

Comment: @YasirArafatSharfi you should have said so in the first place. `CRegKey` is a class in the ATL framework, do you have `#include` statements in your code for the ATL header files? Doesn't sound like it. `CRegKey` is defined in `<atlbase.h>`

Comment: ya i have added <atlbase.h>.. but that is disturbing my other test cases

Comment: i am getting error in other test cases header file like IAccessible ambiguous symbol failed

Comment: and how will i define TEXT here.... its telling TEXT must have class type